# Selecting a button, list object has no attribute click python selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

After searching for a while an answer to my question, I couldn't get an answer that helped me, so here I am asking for your help ! :)

Right now, I am trying to select a plan on a website page which, after it has been selected (Read : a certain button clicked) displays the rest of the page where I can send the keys / values that I want to send.

Here is the code I am using

```
select_plan = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='PostAdMainForm']/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button")
select_plan.click()
```

I found the xpath with Firepath, but when I run my code it gives me a AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Here is the page I am trying to click from

https://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=214&hpGalleryAddOn=false&postAs=ownr

(I am looking to click on the left button, the one in blue)

Thank you very much for you help :)

Comment: I clicked your link, but I don't see a blue button. Only a list of Canadian provinces.

Comment: You would have to click on the post ad on the top right after selecting a province and a city ! Sorry, I thought the link would get you directly where you had to be. 

I did get the solution to my problem though ! Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method find_element**s** returns a *list*, not a single element. You are taking the result and trying to click on it. Like the error says, you can't click on a list.

Either use `find_element` (singular) or use `find_elements` (plural) and then click on one of the elements that was returned.

```
# using find_elements
select_plans = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='PostAdMainForm']/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button")
if len(select_plans) > 0:
    select_plans[0].click()

# using find_element
select_plan = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='PostAdMainForm']/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button")
if select_plan:
    select_plan.click()
```

Comment: Wow... I feel so dumb. I'm really sorry for the question, your answer was exactly the problem I had ! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Could I ask you why you are using the if statement for this ? Is it so that in the case it doesn't find the element, the script doesn't crash ?

Comment: @Maude: yes, it's to protect against no elements matching the xpath.

Comment: Thank you for the specification :)

Answer (score 0):

Though, the link for the page you shared did not have the blue button. However, I have found it, after navigating to 'Post Your Ad' page. You can click on the **Select** button which is in blue color using the text appearing before it. For example, using text **Basic**, you can reach to the **Select** button. Following code shows, how we can achieve this:

```
select_plan = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[text()='Basic']/following::button[text()='Select'][1]")
select_plan.click()
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.